# How to display a random picture from a folder?

Tags: python

I have to display a random image from a folder using Python. I've tried

```
import random, os
random.choice([x for x in os.listdir("path")if os.path.isfile(x)])
```

but it's not working for me (it gives Windows Error: wrong directory syntax, even though I've just copied and paste).

Which could be the problem...

Comment: What is the name of your folder? Is it `path`?

Comment: Is this the exact code you are using? Is the directory you are storing your folder really called "path"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify correct relative path:

```
random.choice([x for x in os.listdir("path")
               if os.path.isfile(os.path.join("path", x))])
```

Otherwise, the code will try to find the files (`image.jpg`) in the current directory instead of the `"path"` directory (`path\image.jpg`).

**UPDATE**

Specify the path correctly. Especially escape backslashes or use `r'raw string literal'`. Otherwise `\..` is interpreted as a escape sequence.

```
import random, os
path = r"C:\Users\G\Desktop\scientific-programming-2014-master\scientific-programming-2014-master\homework\assignment_3\cifar-10-python\cifar-10-batches-py"
random_filename = random.choice([
    x for x in os.listdir(path)
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
])
print(random_filename)
```

Comment: But that's what I've done, I specified the path of the folder (instead of "path" I put the folder path, of course).

Comment: @theggg, In the code in the question, you put only `x` instead of `os.path.join("path", x)`

Comment: I still have the same syntax error, like the name of the path has something wrong.

Comment: @theggg, Please update your question with the real code with the full traceback.

Comment: @theggg, No you tried to edit my answer. rejected. I updated the answer according to your edit attempt. Check it out.

Comment: @theggg, Please try the updated code, and let me know the result. I will go to be soon ;)

Comment: I have an output, even though is not an image, but this depends on the type of the files I have. I'll try to solve this bymyself, for the rest it's working. Thank you.